# How to make status code as 404 in next.js using ISR with fallback:"blocking"?

Tags: javascript, next.js

If route does not match then how we can redirect to 404 error page and make status code as 404 in network tab with ISR `fallback:"blocking"`?

Answer (score 1):

Return the following from `getStaticProps`:

```
return {
  notFound: true,
};
```

See more docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#notfound).

Comment: without using getStaticProps is there any other way ?

Comment: If there's no matching `page` for a route, Next.js will return 404 automatically.